# MySQL error when getting variable from URL

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code I have, but I get this error when I try to get variable from the url: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

The URL variable DEVID is a long string of characters, numbers, dashes, and underscores. Any ideas on what is wrong?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("server","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $user WHERE DEVID=$DEVID");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if (($row["FN"]) == NULL){
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=../register/default.php?user=';
echo $_GET["user"];
echo '&DEVID=';
echo $_GET["DEVID"];
echo '">Please hold, we are taking you to the registration page.<br/><br/>';
}

  }


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` right after your mysql_query and google about sql injections. PS: any reason to show user `please hold` page instead of immediate redirect?

Comment: Is this your full code? If it is, I don't see any variables named `$user` or `$DEVID`. If by `$user` you meant a table named `user`, then remove the `$` sign, and add another check just before the while loop - `if ($result)`.......

Comment: I was asked to put in the please hold..

Comment: the variables are in the URL... They come to the page with the URL formatted like default.php?user=name&DEVID=m0mvtRLb3Mm9c8ZlKa8_S2J5L-J35caA7eqQHb_DQ1a4pbOMmag0Mrt_Nz72VH48PQcMmt44Yxaic_NRXQqW-b3nSGgs3VLBp21Ii942DaZIhW0PqNi1wERne1jT7to30

Comment: Do you `GET[]` them from the URL in some other piece of code? You need to do that before you use them, I believe. Like this: `$user = GET['user'];` And this is a SQL injection waiting to happen... I'd make sure to scrub the variables at least.

Comment: What is the URL to this page? I'm sure there are *many* people that would *love* to help "test" this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $DEVID is a VARCHAR field then you'll need single quotes around it in your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM $user WHERE DEVID='$DEVID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `$DEVID` being set before the query?  You're not using PHP [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), and that's coming from a query-string variable are you?  This is 2012! When are people going to stop using that?

Answer (score 0):

Do the variables $user and $DEVID has values? Have they been initialized ?

Assuming that $user and $DEVID has been initailized the error is happening because mysql_query is returning false as the SQL query generates error when executed.

Moreover you should not use variables directly obtained from the URL. Clean the value for possible presence of single qoutes. Use [mysql_real_esacape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Replace the mysql_query line with the below to see the SQL error if it occurs.

```
$DEVID=mysql_real_escape_string($DEVID);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $user WHERE DEVID='$DEVID'") or die(mysql_error());
```